# Pdf and xlsx with same checksum in R

Tags: r, pdf

I have many projects where I'm required to produce pdf images, and this goes into git and svn repositories.

However, when a pdf is generated in R, it has a different checksum every time. Same happens with creating excel sheets with write.xlsx. So the repositories become cluttered with "changes" which are not real changes.

I imagine that some metadata is added (maybe a timestamp?). Is there a way to strip this from the pdf so that every time I re-generate them, the checksum remains the same?

Comment: Is that so? `tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf");res <- replicate(5, {pdf(tf);plot(0);dev.off();digest::digest(tf, file=TRUE)});length(unique(res))==1 `.

Comment: I guess not easily or on a practical way. Actually checksums are made to not be possible to predict (I know there are ways showing it is possible but not on a regular basis. In general I exclude my pdf files and excel files from the git, since they are created from my code.

Comment: @lukeA you forgot to add a sleep. Put a Sys.sleep(2) before pdf(tf).

Comment: @drmariod my boss like both. Gotta do it.

Comment: @Fabio Oh, I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for pdfs: instead of using pdf(), use cairo_pdf(). The md5sum is stable.